# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbours'

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn, module, sklearn-pandas

I am beginner in machine learning and did find what's going wrong in
this module

**error**...

```
from sklearn.neighbours import KNeighborsClassifier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbours'
```

Comment: check if this module is installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrong import, You should import `KNeighborsClassifier` like this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
```

Comment: please consider this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers